# Tips on refactoring/optimising a chunk of jQuery code

Tags: jquery, optimization, refactoring

I'm building a little "walkthrough" type guide with tooltips using jquery.

When the page loads, a section of the page will have a tool tip saying "step 1" next to it and when they click on the required area, that disapears and "step 2" will appear further down the page.

My code works but I'm just looking for advice on how to improve and optimise what I've written or perhaps a way of simplifying the entire process. I've already tried using variables in places like the $('.helpTip') selector but I believe i'll have to then define that var within each click function which is a bit pointless right?

Anyway, the code:

```
$('.box1').append('<div class="helpTip">Step 1. <span>text</span></div>');

$('.box1 li').click(function() {
    $('.helpTip').fadeOut().remove();
    $('.box2').append('<div class="helpTip">Step 2. <span>text</span></div>');
});

$('.box2 p').click(function() {
    $('.helpTip').fadeOut().remove();
    $('.box3').append('<div class="helpTip">Step 3. <span>text</span></div>');
});

$('.box3 div').click(function() {
    $('.helpTip').fadeOut().remove();
    $('.box4').append('<div class="helpTip">Step 4. <span>text</span></div>');
});

$('.box4 div').click(function() {
    $('.helpTip').fadeOut().remove();
    $('.box5').append('<div class="helpTip">Step 5. <span>text</span></div>');
});

$('.box5').click(function() {
    $('.helpTip').fadeOut().remove();
    // Do something to the submit button?
});
```

HTML if it helps:

```
<!-- Step 1 -->
<div class="formWrap">  
    <div class="formInner">
        <div class="formHeader">
            <h3>1. </h3>
        </div>
        <div class="box1">

        </div>
    </div>                      
</div>

<!-- Step 2 -->
<div class="formWrap">
    <div class="formInner">
        <div class="box2">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>                  

<!-- Step 3 -->
<div class="formWrap">
    <div class="formInner">
        <h3 class="formHeader">3. </h3>
        <div class="box3">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>  

<!-- Step 4 -->
<div class="formWrap">
    <div class="formInner">
        <h3 class="formHeader">4. </h3>
        <div class="box4">


        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Step 5 -->
<div class="formWrap">
    <div class="formInner">
        <h3 class="formHeader">5. </h3>
        <div class="box5">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you also post your HTML structure so we can see how best to optimise this.

Comment: Updated Op with it. I removed the actual content just to make it a little easier to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are my recommendations, FWIW:

- If there are no other elements with a class of "box1", I would change
  that to an ID. Then you could target the elements using just
  `$('#box1')` and it would be a lot faster.
- You can use the `delegate()` method to target elements under your "box" elements. This is
  generally more efficient. So you'd end up with `$('#box1').delegate('li', 'click', function () {});`
- Use context to make your queries more efficient. For instance `$('.helpTip')` will search the entire DOM looking for any element with a class of "helpTip". It appears what you're looking to do is target only the "helpTip" inside the current box.
- Cache as many of the queries as you can.

Basically the code gets more like:

```
var $box1 = $('#box1'),
    $box2 = $('#box2'),
    $box3 = $('#box3'),
    $box4 = $('#box4'),
    $box5 = $('#box5');
$box1.delegate('li', 'click', function () {
    var $this  = $(this);
    $('.helpTip', $this).fadeOut().remove();
    $box2.append('<div class="helpTip">Step 2. <span>text</span></div>');
});
```

Et cetera...

Comment: Thanks for this, however I seem to be getting an error:

"$box1.delegate is not a function"

Comment: Hmm... Maybe you're using an older version of jQuery? `delegate` was added in 1.4.2: http://api.jquery.com/delegate/. Also, make sure $box1 is a jQuery object.

Comment: Working now. No idea what I changed to get it working! Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

For starters, store your jQuery contexts in variables, second use delegates, live or the new on for attaching events.

e.g.

```
    var box1 = $('.box1');
    var box2 = $('.box2');

    box1.append('<div class="helpTip">Step 1. <span>text</span></div>');

    $('li', box1).on("click", function() {
        $('.helpTip').fadeOut().remove();
        box2.append('<div class="helpTip">Step 2. <span>text</span></div>');
    });
...
```

you could also do this:

```
var box1 = $('.box1');
var box2 = $('.box2');
var box3 = $('.box3');
var box4 = $('.box4');
var box5 = $('.box5');

$('.box1 li, .box2 p, .box3 div, .box4 div, .box5').on("click", function() {
    var currentContext = $(this);   
        $('.helpTip', currentContext).fadeOut().remove();

    if (currentContext.hasClass(".box5")) {
        // Do something to the submit button        
    }
    else {
        // write some method to figure out which box to append help to.
    }
});
```

Comment: I agree with Mike point "If there are no other elements with a class of "box1", I would change that to an ID. Then you could target the elements using just $('#box1') and it would be a lot faster."

Answer (score 1):

couldn't you loop throught an array that contains the elements? something like:

```
var appended = ['Step 1. <span>text</span>',
            'Step 2. <span>text</span>',
            'Step 3. <span>text</span>',
            'Step 4. <span>text</span>',
            'Step 5. <span>text</span>'
            ];
var selector = ['.box1 li','.box2 div','.box3 div','.box4 div','.box5']
var help = $('.helpTip');
function fader(){
    help.fadeOut().remove();
}
$('.box1').append('<div class="helpTip">'+appended[0]+'</div>');
var i = 0;
var box = '.box';
$(selector[i]).live('click',function(){ //if the elements already exist you should use .click or bind('click')wasn't sure if this was the situation

    app = box+(i+2);
    if (app === '.box5'){
        fader();   
    } else {
        fader();
        $(app).append('<div class="helpTip">'+appended[i+1]+'</div>')
        i++;    
    }


})
```

I'm sorry I could test this (lack of time on my side and lack of html from your side.. better attach a jsfiddle for a question like this) so basically this is psuedo code. not sure this would optimize speed (this already covered well with @Mike-McCaughan answer) but would scale better if this list is much longer, also keeps it DRY.

if you'll follow @Mike-McCaughan good advice then the 'selector' array can be removed and the beginning of the function should be changed accordingally